# why for some values there is an infinity result but no for others?

Tags: java, max

first, sorry about my bad English...

today i tried to check if Integer.MAX_VALUE*Integer.MAX_VALUE

```
    System.out.println("long*long= "+Long.MAX_VALUE*Long.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("int*int= "+Integer.MAX_VALUE*Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("double*double= "+Double.MAX_VALUE*Double.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("float*float= "+Float.MAX_VALUE*Float.MAX_VALUE);
    System.out.println("short*short= "+Short.MAX_VALUE*Short.MAX_VALUE);
```

the results:

long*long= 1

int*int= 1

double*double= Infinity

float*float= Infinity

short*short= 1073676289

why is that? if float^2=Infinity, so long^2 should also be Infinity... and 1 is clearly a mistake...
anyone have any idea? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For seeing how integers multiply, use the binary notation. For simplicity's sake I use a 4 bit signed integer (where the MAX is 7), but the principle is the same for byte, short, int and long.

```
      0111 x 0111
      ----
      0111
     0111
    0111
   -------
    110001

 The columns from right to left:
 1) 1 => 1
 2) 1+1 => 10 => 0 and carry 1c into 3)
 3) 1+1+1+1c => 100 => 0 and carry 1c into 5) (sic! 5)
 4) 1+1 => 10 => 0 and carry 1c into 5)
 5) 1+1c+1c => 11
```

Higher order bits are irrelevant because truncated.

This isn't even a peculiarity of Java - it is the consequence of two's complement arithmetic modulo^(number of bits).

Comment: understood. it is just weird, but i guess there is no better way for this kind of things... thank you!

Comment: (+1) for the long binary multiplication. Please could you add a brief remark about the carry; it had me confused for a few minutes (I couldn't figure out why 1+1+1 was giving 0 in the answer - d'oh!). Thanks

Comment: @NPE Thanks - I was using an excess line. Now 7x7 = 49 = 32+16+1

Comment: @NPE OK, done. - I once tried to do this off the cuff in class and started floundering. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17.1 says

> If an integer multiplication overflows, then the result is the
>   low-order bits of the mathematical product as represented in some
>   sufficiently large two's-complement format.

Your integer answers are too large to fit in the result type, so the high-order bits of the true answer are simnply discarded.

(2^n-1) * (2^n -1) is 2^2n - 2*2^n + 1, which is 1 modulo 2^n - so you are getting the expected answer.

The rules for floating point types are different.

Comment: well, this sum it up very well, thanks... but i'm still didn't understood why double and float (floating points) have Infinity and long/int doesn't have...

Comment: They're designed _very_ differently.  Among other things, `double` and `float` are expected to represent inexact values to limited precision, which is not the case with `int` and `long`.

Answer (score 2):

> long^2 should also be Infinity

Only floating-point types have a special value for infinity. Integer types do not; this includes `long`.

`Long.MAX_VALUE * Long.MAX_VALUE` evaluates to `1` is due to [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), since `((2**63 -1) ** 2) mod (2**64) == 1` ([Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%282**63%20-1%29%20**%202%29%20mod%20%282**64%29)).

Comment: okay then, but why 1? and also why integer types doesn't have this special value?

Comment: @Moshe9362: Integer overflow; see the updated answer. The reason integers can't represent infinity directly is, I suspect, largely historic (two's complement could have been extended to have reserved values such as infinity).

Comment: okay, thank you very much you have helped me to understand Java better @MarkRotteveel

Answer (score 0):

Because 2^63 -1 * 2^63 -1 is not infinite, you need a variable that can store the answer of this equation. the default call is unable to print it but it has answer. which is reflected by true(1)